# Java Instantiating Array of Class in class space yields NullPointerException

Tags: java, variables, nullpointerexception, instantiation

I'm new to Java (coming from C# among other languages) and if I create a variable and instantiate it in the empty space of a class like so;

```
private SomeClass[][] someClassArray = new SomeClass[5][5];
```

I then receive a NullPointerException. However if I don't instantiate there but rather in a method it works fine. It seems like other times I can get away with this.

I tried looking this up in docs but didn't have any luck. Can someone provide some feedback or links to explain this so I understand how to properly instantiate in Java?

**Edit:**

In this instance it is error'ing when using `someClassArray.length` in an if statement. Why would this work correctly when instantiating in a method but not in the class.

The following is another example in which I get the NullPointerException when assigning a value...

```
public class LevelClass extends SomeOtherClass{

    private Map<String, LevelItemKeyClass> levelItemKeys = new HashMap<String, LevelItemKeyClass>();

    private void CreateKeys() {
        levelItemKeys.put(new LevelItemKeyClass("abc")); //NullPointerException occurs here
    }
}
```

In the same manner as the above case, it works fine when instantiated in a method but not the class. The below works as expected;

```
public class LevelClass extends SomeOtherClass{

    private Map<String, LevelItemKeyClass> levelItemKeys;

    private void CreateKeys() {
        levelItemKeys = new HashMap<String, LevelItemKeyClass>();

        levelItemKeys.put(new LevelItemKeyClass("abc"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `private SomeClass[][] someClassArray = new SomeClass[5][5]();` ?

Comment: Initializing it that way should work fine. You'll need to show more code for anyone to help find the problem.

Comment: What is "the empty space of a class" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me the issue is in the difference in the order that instance variables are initialized compared to the constructor between JAVA and C#.

Answer (score 3):

You are instantiating a double-dimension array of `SomeClass` with capacity `5 * 5`.

This will never throw a `NullPointerException` **unless** some static initializer in `SomeClass` throws it (which would actually throw a `ExceptionInInitializerError` anyway). 
 likely, you are then trying to access any array element, which is initialized as `null` by default (non-initialized `Object`s all have `null` default value), and then invoking an instance method, which would throw `NullPointerException`.

In short, before invoking any method on `someClassArray[x][y]`, you need to initialize that element, e.g.:

```
someClassArray[x][y] = new SomeClass();
```

**Edit**

Since your question has changed quite a lot...
If you are experiencing a `NullPointerException` in this statement:

```
levelItemKeys.put(new LevelItemKeyClass('abc')); // NullPointerException occurs here
```

... and your `levelItemKeys` map is initialized before modification, it means the NPE has been thrown in your constructor. Which you haven't posted the code for.

I'd recommend using a debugger.

Comment: Thanks @Mena but I'm not sure that is the case here. Please see my edit.